# windows C system call with spaces in command

Tags: c, windows, command-line, escaping

I cannot make system calls with spaces in the names and parameters. For example:

```
system("c:\\program files\\something\\example.exe c:\\my files\\example.txt");
```

I have tried escaping in every way I know how, and NOTHING works. I have tried:

```
system("\"c:\\program files\\something\\example.exe\" \"c:\\my files\\example.txt\"");
```

and

```
system("c:\\program^ files\\something\\example.exe c:\\my^ files\\example.txt");
```

Neither work. I still get 'c:\program' is not a recongnised internal or external command

This is really driving me mad... I need to call and pass parameters that have spaces in them. I cannot use the short notation for reasons I won't go into.

I have tried with ' quotes instead of " quotes, still doesn't work. I have tried putting quotes around the whole thing and quotes around the spaces and that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do it properly?

Answer (score 31):

**Edit:** OK, figured it out by stepping into the `system()` call: you need an extra set of quotes around the whole thing due the fact that it internally calls **cmd /c** *yourinput*

So this works for me:

```
system("\"\"c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe\" \"www.stackoverflow.com\"\"");
```

A bit of a mess, isn't it?

Comment: Ooops I have been especaping slashes.
The reason I need it to work with system is because I am also using _open etc.

Comment: Edited - try the double quotes.

Comment: How about this?

system(&("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe") "www.stackoverflow.com")

Reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/07/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path.aspx

Comment: Is this a Windows-specific thing, or does UNIX also have this behaviour?