# C++ parsing a command line

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to run two of the command lines in a C++ program, but landing in a strange error. The command lines that i want to run are

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev='USB Video Device' :dshow-adev=""  :live-caching=50 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{dst=localhost:1234},dst=display} :sout-keep

vlc -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50
```

They both run fine on command prompt. But when in use a C++ system shell call to run these, the first one fails, where as second one works. The way i run these in C++ is as follows:

```
system( "\"G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc\" -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev=\"USB Video Device\" :dshow-adev=\"none\"  :live-caching=50 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{dst=localhost:1234},dst=display}:sout-keep");

system( "\"G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc\" -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50");
```

The first command throws an error "G:/Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", which is strange since the way both commands handle path to the file is the same. Please let me know the reason for this.
The computer is running on Windows XP and i am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Add \ before the space in your path.

Comment: But there isn't a \ before the space in the second command too, but that works. Thanks anyways. I shall try this!

Comment: Adding \ does not work too!

Comment: Try putting the whole system cmd in a char* variable. Try to print the string first and then pass that variable to system. This way you can make out if the parsing of the cmd is correct or not.

Comment: Generally this error comes when you don't wrap the path with spaces in quotes to avoid the string parsing delimiter of "space" by console. But that seems to be not a problem in your shown code.

Comment: Can you show the output of this::
char* temp = "Your first cmd parameter to system call" ;
printf( "%s", temp ) ;

char* temp1 = "Your second cmd parameter to system call" ;
printf( "%s", temp1 ) ;

Comment: @Abhineet: Do you mean the output of the command line? So i'm basically trying to stream audio and video using vlc. The first command is to stream data at the server and the second command is at the client to receive and play the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40695/discussion-between-vigo-and-abhineet)

Comment: +1 I never knew this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
system( "\"G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc\" -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev=\"USB Video Device\" :dshow-adev=\"none\"  :live-caching=50 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{dst=localhost:1234},dst=display}:sout-keep");

system( "\"G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc\" -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50");
```

with

```
system( "G:\\\"Program Files\"\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev=\"USB Video Device\" :dshow-adev=\"none\"  :live-caching=50 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{dst=localhost:1234},dst=display}:sout-keep");

system( "G:\\\"Program Files\"\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50");
```

Comment: Doesn't work too, since the file path is being read as "G:/"Program Files"/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc". I think the extra quotes is causing the problem. Gives an error "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Do let me know if the edited solution works for you.

Comment: No..it doesn't! the same error "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect." again

Comment: Are you sure that the path provided by you is correct. Can you run the vlc from the path in cmd prompt?

Comment: Yes! i can even run the entire streaming command from cmd prompt. But i want to initiate streaming using the same command from a C++ function.

Comment: This edition is my final try. Would you plz check against this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40712/discussion-between-vigo-and-abhineet)

Comment: i missed out. Could you pls tell me which is your final edition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using `system()` to run commands has the following caveats and switch requirements for what you are attempting (from cmd documentation) as it effectively runs `cmd /C *mycommandhere*`:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

If you reformat your commands as:

```
    system("cmd /S /C \"\"c:\\testDir\"\"\\dir with spaces\"\"\\myexe.exe");
```

that should work:) ( in the previous version I had forgotten some escape characters).

There is also a [related question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642551/windows-c-system-call-with-spaces-in-command)

Or if it is for windows only You could utilise [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with some documentation on the aforementioned at [msdn, here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope this helps, as I just lost connection to my home environment and cannot get a fixed version for my previous fix at present, will do so tonight however.

Comment: this gives "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" error!

Comment: I will re-check I have typed the right format, may have missed something apologies.