# how can i execute a file kept on desktop in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

my file structure for executing a .exe is something like this
c:\Documents and settings\Desktop\Release\abc.exe
i want to execute this from other c++ program in vb c++ after building, it generates an error that c:\Document is not external or internal command
few lines of code are as follows:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main( void ) {
 int result;
 result=system("c:\\Documents and settings\\Desktop\\Release\\abc.exe");
 getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to escape the space.

Comment: i also know that dear. i think u can see that i already put backslash for that purpose.. btw why this downvote for?

Comment: That looks like the same error you'd get if you tried to type that command in a console window. As such, I'd try the same thing you do when in the console window - wrap the command with quotes. Not just enclose the command, but include quotes in it. Such that the string passed to your call to system is `"c:\\Documents and settings\\Desktop\\Release\\abc.exe"`, rather than just `c:\\Documents and settings\\Desktop\\Release\\abc.exe`, as it is now. Try the following: `result=system("\"c:\\Documents and settings\\Desktop\\Release\\abc.exe\"");` - `\"` contained in a string inserts the `"` char.

Comment: @Sandesh By "escape the space", I mean you must escape **THE SPACE.** Not the backslashes. **Do you know what the difference between a space and a backslash is?**

Comment: i know the difference sir.. with due respect can you help me out in this case.. please don't give suggestions..

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows C system call with spaces in command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642551/windows-c-system-call-with-spaces-in-command)

Comment: @Jaywalker - bingo! I should have searched for that. :embarrassed:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected when writing an earlier comment, the way to do it is to wrap the entire string in double-quotes. 'Escaping the spaces' sounds non-sensical to me. 25 seconds of googling and I don't see (nor have I heard of in over 20 years) an escape-sequence for a space character in C.

The solution is indeed to include quotes in the string - not to just wrap the string in a single pair of them, as you've done. The following will do the trick:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int result;
    result = system("\"c:\\Documents and settings\\Desktop\\Release\\abc.exe\"");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

However, that said - you shouldn't really be using the `system` call for this job. Since you're on a windows machine, you should use the `ShellExecute` function instead. There are many reasons for this, which I wont go into here, you can look them up yourself. But suffice to say it's an infinitely better way to invoke another program.

More on `ShellExecute`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx