# Error when running symbolic link with system

Tags: c, cmd

I have problem whenever i try to execute a path in a c program like this ,

```
system("cmd /c \"C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\sdlmenutest\\program t.lnk\"") ;
```

i get this error

"The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again."

but it does exist , so how to fix it ?

Comment: Count the number of (escaped) double-quotes `"` in the string.

Comment: system("cmd /c \"C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\sdlmenutest\\program t.lnk\"") ;

Comment: sorry still the same problem

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642551/windows-c-system-call-with-spaces-in-command

Comment: @user2760375 i tried it although we didn't have the same error but it didn't work , the problem is when i run directly this command in cmd it works but when i run it with system, i get that error

Comment: @satrter you write " i tried it although we didn't have the same error but it didn't work". If you didn't get the same error, what error did you get then ?

Comment: the one i mentioned first "The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again."

Comment: just a guess: try to add (as first argument) the Option "/S" and explicitly say cmd.exe

Comment: @satrter, after removing the duplicate double quote at the end, if it is still failing, check the number of requires \\ to actually escape a single \ in windows. I've see some situations where \\\ is required. \\ to escape a single \ (to be used as the actual escape).

Comment: @vlad_tepesch i did what you told me but now and know nothing happens  (the program doesn't launch and no errors )

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if it wa a problem of escaping \ i would have this error in the cmd "not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file "

Comment: Not necessarily. The `cmd` portion of the call is not escaped. I've even seen \\\\ required at times...

Comment: Could the error message refer to the link _target_ or _Start in_ directory rather than to the `.lnk` file?

Comment: the error refers to the link target @JosefZ

Comment: the exact error " C:\Users\asus\Desktop\sdlmenutest\program t.lnk The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again "

Comment: What happens if you double click the `program t.lnk` file? What kind of link (target extension)? Link to a network source?

Comment: when i double click it launches and the target extension is .exe