# Python 3 Backup Failed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I just followed totorial《A Byte of Python》,there is a problem to back up all important files.

Here is my code:

```
import os

import time

source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']

target_dir = 'D:\\Backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + \
         time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.Zip'

if not os.path.exists(target_dir):

    os.mkdir(target_dir)

zip_command = 'zip -r {0} {1}'.format(target,
                                      ' '.join(source))

print('Zip command is:')

print(zip_command)

print('Running:')

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:

      print('Successful backup to', target)
else:
      print('Backup Failed')
```

Although I am on windows system, I think I have added **C:\Windows\GnuWin32\bin** to system PATH environment variable.[Is it right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIXi1.png) 
When I type zip in terminal [it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uErT.png)

But when I run the program, the result is:

```
Zip command is:
zip -r D:\Backup\20170310193946.Zip "C:\My Documents" C:\Code
Running:
Backup Failed
```

I have tried again and again, still don't know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: OK, can't really test due to lack of Windows, but it's possible that the paths in your command passed to `os.system()` got interpreted as C backslash-escaped characters.  Python's `os.system` is really a wrapper around C's `system(3)`. I suspect there might be some [escape-character craziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642551/windows-c-system-call-with-spaces-in-command) going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: [Don't use `os.system` at all](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements). It's evil and confusing anyway. Make sure the paths you pass to the child process are exactly meant to be what they are.  Use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#module-os.path) when necessary. The backslash characters as path separators are retarded and evil and you should take care, because escapogeddon is retarded.

Comment: Sorry, I still can not understand it.Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are using linux zip command, it should be somrthing different on windows.

Comment: Hi Nice to talk with you again. But I have installed **zip command**, this should not the issue,right?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Because I have installed **zip command**, so this should not be the issue, right?

Comment: If you do have a zip command line application then you should use `subproces` module instead of os.system

Comment: @Granitosaurus My god! Finally I sloved it.Thanks for your great help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you installed **zip 3.0** from the **GnuWin32** website.
2. Maybe you need to change **system path environment variable** from `C:\Windows\GnuWin32\bin` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`.
3. Restart IDE (in my case it was PyCharm) after changing the path.